# ¿Es posible darle estilo a todas las ocurrencias de una palabra en un texto?

Tags: css, color

Me gustaría saber si es posible hacer esto que contemplo:

Tenemos un texto que y quiero que resalte X Palabra, por ejemplo, Cada vez que ponga "Hola" aparezca escrito en Azul. Sin tener que etiquetar en cada palabra, sino configurar el styles.css para que cuando haya un "Hola" en la página lo ponga directmente en azul.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solo con `css` no va ser posible, te dejo un código de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23864695/2097224) cual funciona con javascript.

Luego puedes usar `css` para buscar las palabras y darle estilo `[word=hola]`:

```js
function makeHighlightable() {
  
  var n;
  var a=[];
  var walk = document.createTreeWalker(document.body,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  
  while (n = walk.nextNode()) a.push(n);
  
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      
      var newSpan = document.createElement('span');      
      var words   = a[i].nodeValue.split(' ');
      
        for(var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
          
            var escapedWord = words[j].replace(/^\w /ig,'');
          
            words[j] = '<span word="'+escapedWord+'">'+words[j]+'</span>';
        }
      
        words = words.join(' ');
        
        newSpan.innerHTML = words;
        
        a[i].parentNode.replaceChild(newSpan,a[i]);
    }
}

makeHighlightable()
```

```css
.hola1 [word=Hóla] { 
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hola2 [word=hóla] { 
  color: darkorange ;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hola3 [word=hola] { 
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="hola1">Hóla hóla ahora sin tilde Hola hola ahora con puntos Hóla::: hóla::: y sin puntos Hóla hóla</p>

<p class="hola2">Hóla hóla ahora sin tilde Hola hola ahora con puntos Hóla::: hóla::: y sin puntos Hóla hóla</p>

<p class="hola3">Hóla hóla ahora sin tilde Hola hola ahora con puntos Hóla::: hóla::: y sin puntos Hóla hóla</p>
```

Comment: Me parece que no se debería eliminar los saltos de línea, hay casos en los que tienen un significado dentro del HTML. Por otro lado, se están coloreando los signos de puntuación alrededor de `hola`, y este caso no funcionaría con palabras con tilde

Answer (score 5):

En complemento a la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/41709/16597) de @aldanux, podemos usar `RegExp` para hacer una búsqueda insensible a las mayúsculas o minúsculas.

```js
function highlight(word) {
  var wordRe = new RegExp('('+word+')', 'ig');
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    null,
    false
  );

  var nodes = [];
  while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    if (treeWalker.currentNode.textContent.match(wordRe)) {
      nodes.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
    }
  }

  var element, i;
  for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    element = document.createElement('span');
    element.innerHTML = nodes[i].textContent.replace(wordRe, '<span class="blue">$1</span>');
    nodes[i].parentNode.replaceChild(element, nodes[i]);
  }
}
highlight('hola');
```

```css
.blue{
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="hola">
  Hola este es un texto de prueba. Asi es hola, es una prueba
  
  Hola este es un texto de prueba. Asi es hola, es una prueba hola
  
  <p>Hola este es un texto de prueba. Asi es hola, es una prueba</p>
  
  Hola este es un texto de prueba. Asi es hola, es una prueba
  
  <p>Hola este es un texto de prueba. Asi es hola, es una prueba as dasd</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, estoy probando pero no consigo que funcione, desde las respuestas que mandáis online va todo Ok, pero al copiar el código no hay manera de que ejecute ese javascript.

Comment: ¿Donde y como estas ubicando el `script`?

Comment: He probado tanto en el propio archivo html como externo, cualquier script me va pero ese no, no entiendo por qué.

Comment: @Jesús, he actualizado mi respuesta. Intenta a ver si así te funciona.

Comment: Esta es claramente la mejor respuesta. Hay un detalle @Marcos, tené en cuenta, a la hora de reemplazar, que un elemento puede tener múltiples textnodes (aunque no entiendo por qué usás el Arrau en vez de reemplazar directamente en el treewalker)... Además, quizás sea buena idea usar `\b` antes y después de la palabra buscada

Comment: Hola @Mariano, gracias por tu comentario. He actualizado mi respuesta para corregir los escenarios donde mi respuesta anterior fallaba. Con respecto a porque no reemplazo directamente cuando itero el `treewalker`, es porque si se modifica alguno de los nodos, automáticamente se pierde la referencia a los demás, es decir, .`treeWalker.nextNode()` devuelve `null`.

Answer (score 1):

**Con solamente CSS no es posible**. Pero con Javascript si se puede, Tendrias que hacer una busqueda en el DOM y reemplazar los textos que tu quieres.

Ej: Buscar "Hola" y reemplazar por `<div class="color-blue">Hola</div>` y en el css deberias tener:

`.color-blue{color:blue;}`

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Esto no es posible simplemente con `CSS`. Sin embargo, puedes usar una regex y la función `replace` de `Javascript` para mostrar todas las ocurrencias de una palabra en un texto de un color determinado.

Lo que hago en este caso es reemplazar (detectando con una regex donde está la palabra `hola`) el `hola` original por un nuevo `hola` que va estar contenido dentro de un `span` con una clase `azul`. Esta clase va a ser la que le de el estilo a la palabra.

Ejemplo:

```js
var span = document.getElementById("texto");
var texto = span.innerHTML;
var textoReemplazado = texto.replace(/hola/g, "<span class=\"azul\">hola</span>");
span.innerHTML = textoReemplazado;
```

```css
.azul{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span id="texto">Texto hola este texto en el que pone hola, y a su vez otra vez hola, pero hola, y hola, y hola otra vez de nuevo.</span>
```

**OBSERVACIÓN:** Este ejemplo no funcionaría si recuperaras el HTML de un contenedor (el cual recuperará también el HTML de los elementos hijos que contenga) si alguno de los elementos hijos tiene como `id` o `clase` la palabra clave que queremos reemplazar, ya que también reemplazará estos ID o clases, lo que provocará que se produzcan inconsistencias en el HTML. Deberías de usarlo con cuidado.

Comment: El problema con esta respuesta es, si en lugar de `hola` se buscara `texto` en el `document.body`, el `HTML` se rompería ya que la cadena `texto` también esta como valor del atributo `id` del `span`