# Cambiar de color a una palabra

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla hecha con `HTML` y `JavaScript`.

```js
var ths = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0; i < ths.length; i++) {

  ths[i].style.color = "red";

}

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {

  tds[i].style.color = "green";

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Y quisiera que por medio de JavaScript Básico (estoy aprendiendo a usarlo y no se mas allá de Jquery) me localice y me modifique el color de una palabra, que en este caso seria `John`
.
Se que puede ser por medio de esta función:

```
color = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
color[6].style.color="green";
```

Pero no hace la función de buscar la palabra, encontrar la palabra y cambiarle 
el color de la palabra.

Comment: para cambiar el color de una sola palabra hay que encerrarla en algun tipo de tag (por ej agregando un `<span>`) lo cual implica modificar el DOM actual. seria un, buscar la palabra y remplazarla por la palabra encerrada en dicho tag... no es algo muy practico para una aplicacion de la vida real. Capaz no entendi bien el post, puedes mejorar la redaccion o hacer las aclaraciones necesarias.

Comment: Hola @EmanuelVe, como lo indique, no quiero nada de HTML o CSS, ya que eso lo se, pero no se usar JavaScript y estoy practicándolo, por eso quiero que todo sea dentro de JavaScript.
Y nuevamente te repito quiero que por medio de JavaScript me localice la palabra "John" y me modifique el color.

Comment: Ya se que estas aprendiendo, por eso te digo, Explica mejor lo que quieres. Buscar la palabra John no es lo mismo que buscar la celda que contiene la palabra John, ni tampoco explica si es una coincidencia exacta o parcial.. esta incompleta la pregunta.

Comment: Le pido que vuelva a leer la ultima parte de mi pregunta, gracias.

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que hay una pregunta similar, lo que pasa es que era sobre hacer highlight o algo así en el texto. Voy a buscarla y la pongo por aqui.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro por favor

Comment: Mira [esta preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/41706/250) y [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/65172/250). Creo que la soluciones de esas dos preguntas te pueden servir para lo que quieres... y estoy casi seguro que debe de haber al menos otra más, porque creo recordar que yo respondí a algo parecido, pero no consigo encontrarla.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Ya resolvi mi problema gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo lo hiciste al final?

Comment: Use el código de @Sakulino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar características avanzadas de JS. Debes usar [document.designMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/designMode) junto con [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) para poder editar el documento.

La mayoría de los comandos afectan a la selección de documento (negrita, cursiva, etc.), mientras que otros insertar nuevos elementos (añadiendo un enlace) o afectan a toda una línea (sangría).

Te muestro cómo quedaria tu código:

```js
    //recuperamos el valor que queremos resaltar
    var text = "John";
    document.designMode = "on";
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.collapse(document.getElementById("resultat"), 0);

    while (window.find(text)) {
        document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "lightgreen");
        sel.collapseToEnd();
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>


</html>
```

[js](/questions/tagged/js)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[css3](/questions/tagged/css3)[html](/questions/tagged/html)

Comment: Hola @sakulino se me hace algo avanzado, como por ejemplo, trato de cambiarle "HiliterColor" por "Color" para que así solo me cambie el color de letra y no me la subraye.
Pero no logro que haga ese cambio... je, si me pudieras decir como pudiera lograr ese cambio por favor

Comment: Prueba con "ForeColor"

Comment: Ya, me funciono gracias